# Not receiving refresh token auth 2.0

Tags: php, yii, oauth, oauth-2.0

Hello I am newbie and using this library
[php auth 2.0](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php)
which seems to be a good solution for using auth 2.0. I am trying to generate refresh token I can receive it. Here is my code:

```
    OAuth2\Autoloader::register();

    // $dsn is the Data Source Name for your database, for exmaple "mysql:dbname=my_oauth2_db;host=localhost"
    $storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array('dsn' => $this->dsn, 'username' => $this->username, 'password' => $this->password));

    // Pass a storage object or array of storage objects to the OAuth2 server class
    $server = new OAuth2\Server($storage,array('always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true,
    'refresh_token_lifetime'         => 2419200,));

    // Add the "Client Credentials" grant type (it is the simplest of the grant types)
    $server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));
    $server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken($storage));
```

Here is request:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/eventapp/index.php/oauth/handle");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ID&client_secret=SECRET");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result=curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
$result=get_object_vars(json_decode($result));
print_r($result);
```

Can anyone help me with this? Please guide me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I would request you to use postman rest client.That way it will be very easy to monitor your exceptions.

Comment: @khakishoiab i am only receiving access token not refresh token

Comment: is there a timeout issue

Comment: no @khakishoiab

Comment: `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ID&client_secret=SECRET`  Is this your actual query

Comment: @khakishoiab  no i am using real id and secret in app

Comment: Good,then is the syntax proper .I mean have you used the same method before?

Comment: By default refresh token is false upon successive hits,check my answer

Comment: did the problem got solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
$grantType = new OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken($storage, array(
    'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true
));
```

**The Refresh Token grant type has the following configuration:**

always_issue_new_refresh_token
whether to issue a new refresh token upon successful token request

```
Default: false
```

So by default its false,you have make it true.

Also check [here](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/refresh-token/)

Example Request

```
$ curl -u TestClient:TestSecret https://api.mysite.com/token -d 'grant_type=password&username=bshaffer&password=brent123'
```

The access token will then contain a refresh token

```
{
"access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
"expires_in":3600,
"token_type": "bearer",
"scope":null,
"refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
```

}

Comment: you can also try `$server = new OAuth2\Server($storage, array(
    'always_issue_new_refresh_token' => true,
    'refresh_token_lifetime'         => 2419200,
));`